# My CSS is only applying to the body and not to a specific class

Tags: html, css, class

This is probably some dumb mistake I'm making but I can't get my styling to apply to the class "searchBar". It applies to the body just fine but when I try and apply it to the class it does nothing. Below is my HTML and CSS.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, gray, skyblue);
};

.searchBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class = "searchBar">
    <h1>Find your game</h1>
    <input type='text' placeholder='search..'>
  </div>

</body>
```

not sure why the closing body tag isn't appearing but it is there.

Answer (score 2):

You should drop the semicolon at the end of body section.

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, gray, skyblue);
}

.searchBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even see that... Knew it was something dumb.Thank you.